# download image and pdf files from any site

Tags: c#

i made a program for  data entry to download any image  also pdfs files form any web site so i want any one help me in this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and the `WebClient` class.